# HTML - <form> tag adds line break

Tags: html, css

OK, so I have this in `<li>` floating to the right... like so:

[image]

and here it is:

```
<div id="right_menu">
<ul>
<li class="search-li"><input placeholder="Search things here..." type="text" class="search-tr" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#right_menu {
    float:right;
    background: #575757;
}
#right_menu ul li a {
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    border-right:0px !important;
}
```

The `search-li` class and `search-tr` have no style. The search menu is wrapped around `#first_menu` and that CSS is:

```
#first_menu {
    background: #333 !important;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
#first_menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #333;
    float: left;
    }
```

Anyway, when I add `<form action="search.php" method="get"> ... </form>` around the `<input>` box inside the `<li>`... I get this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Thanks

edit: On second thought, not even sure that adding form and pressing enter would even work...

Comment: are you reseting your css? can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: does `form` have some css attached to it somewhere?

Comment: It is hard to answer without real example. Can you make a jsfiddle or other demo? Have you tried to inspect element and find out where this space from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FORMs are block elements, therefore they add a line-break. Reset the form's CSS so it doesn't.

Use:

```
form {
   display:inline;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Using `!important` is a sign that do know how CSS specificity works. It's good to [read up on this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Also, it's good to start with a [CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/), which would prevent this form layout problem completely.

Comment: Apparently the <li class="search-li"> is creating a 0x18 break... hold on.

Comment: There is no need for an unordered list that contains ONE item. Get rid of it.

Comment: AH okay, I removed the <li> and applied a CSS reset and it fixed it. Thanks.